# What to do when a professor gives an undeserved D to a PhD Student?

Tags: phd, professorship

If a professor gives a D for a student "just because", what can the student do?
In previous classes, this student was called ridiculous in the front of all the others, and this professor was always saying bad things about her.
Knowing that a D is a shameful, cut-off  (one can lose their funding) kind of grade, the professor just gave it to the student.

What should one do in this case? It is like someone has the power to crash one's career. It is wrong on every possible level.

Please, help.
Academia should have moral standards, and things like this should never occur.

It happened with my partner this morning. She is in shock. She is so brilliant and hardworking. She may have had her career ended today.

P.s: Sorry for the mistakes. I wrote it blindly.

Comment: What course? What level? What topic? Evidence that it is "just because" rather than justified (you would be surprised how often students overestimate themselves - not saying this is the case here, but you should have some stronger argument than that, e.g. for the student ombudsman etc.).

Comment: I understand. I do not think the bad grades are because of the professor's bad intentions in general cases, but this (one) professor offended her several times. Can you understand how it is not only an "oh my God, she can never be wrong". I am only in this forum because it must be a certain way to processed. And what reason can one give, if one cannot say the professor is wrong. What are the steps? This was my question. Should she talk with the adm of the faculty, etc.;

Comment: I would never come here with a "ego" problem. I know how this forum works, and I know it would delete any questions on "how one feels about academia". It is a serious thing, and it should concern all of us.

Comment: Has she consulted her advisor about this?

Comment: @mathlanguagetruth I did not say it's an ego problem. What I said is - what is your evidence, because this is what you can work from. Example: prof insists on something that is patently wrong (e.g. standard textbooks show it is wrong, and it is not a scientifically contentious issue), against the student's opinion. Insults and bullying are a more general issue, and, again - get evidence. Record what has happened over a period, and when; be accurate in description. With this, go to the ombudsperson/HR/student services/whoever is responsible for dealing with bullying.

Comment: Dear @patricia, she is very concerned about the outcome, as they might be very close (her adviser and this professor).
He did not even say why a D, just gave a D. She would have changed any wrong thing if he had asked her to. It was really biased strange unethical behavior.  So, we do not know what to do. How to prove that someone was unethical. It is really hard.

Comment: @mathlanguagetruth Captain Emacs has given you a path forward: Record the professor's behavior. Collect factual evidence. Present your evidence to people whose job it is to help you: ombudsperson, advisor, grievance committee, capricious grading committee, graduate program director, department head, dean, whoever.  **And then listen.**

Comment: Also: Has your friend asked the professor directly why he gave her a D?

Comment: With whomever you talk with, you'll also need to be more clear on what the grade is for (the class as a whole, or one particular assignment?), and on what the syllabus for the course says the grading scheme is. It's very unusual to have no set rubric for grade determination, no grades during the semester, and only a single final grade at the very end. This is so unusual that anyone you deal with will want to know these things first, so this information will need to be collected and understood to bring to whoever the first contact with.

Comment: "It's very unusual to have no set rubric for grade determination, no grades during the semester, and only a single final grade at the very end." Actually, in my experience as both a graduate student and a graduate instructor, this has been the most common situation.  On the other hand, I take the meaning of this to be "We have moved beyond caring so much about grades," with the effect that the grade given is usually an A.

Answer (score 18):

I would advise her to discuss this with her advisor. Do not push the "unethical behavior" idea. Instead, focus on two points:

- She does not understand the reasons for the D.
- She is concerned about the consequences for her funding etc.

All the better if the advisor is close to the professor who gave the D. It makes the advisor a better potential advocate. No professor likes to have a PhD student fail - it makes them look bad.

Answer (score 8):

Many institutions have a formal process for appealing a class grade.  Some university official, such as a department chair, would review the student's work and grade records to determine if the grade was assigned fairly in accordance with the class's grade policies.  If not, the official can assign a different grade.

Usually this sort of appeal only succeeds if there is something clearly and objectively wrong with the way the grade was assigned; they won't usually overrule the instructor on subjective matters (e.g. "did this paper show enough insight to be worth an A").  A common standard is that the grade will only be changed if the investigation concludes that the original grade was assigned in an "arbitrary and capricious" manner.  It sounds like you think that is what happened, but I would suggest first discussing the matter informally with the department chair or some trusted faculty member who is familiar with the process, to see if they agree that there is evidence to support your claim.

Comment: +1 The chair or the graduate student advisor / director of graduate studies.